# Segmentation Error 11 Upon calling Struct Member

Tags: c, struct

Based on my current understanding it's something related to not allocating memory properly.

I don't understand why can it print item->key and not call the compare function? The struct item* item is already in the memory I guess?

Any advice? been stuck for quite awhile

```
struct item
{
    char* key;
    struct item *left;
    struct item *right;
};


int compare(char* A, char* B){
  return strcmp(A, B);
}

struct item* insert(struct item* item, char* key)
{
    printf ("(%s):",key);

     printf ("(%s)\n",item->key); // I can do Node->Key here

     compare(item->key, key); // I cant do node->key here // Segmentation Error
}
```

Potential fix? I tried allocating it a memory and loading the item into it. Still the same result too. Just trying anything I can find :(

```
struct item* item = (struct item*) malloc(sizeof(struct item));
```

Comment: don't you think that the declaration of `struct item` might be useful to us?

Comment: @MikeNakis No, that's totally irrelevant. ;-)

Comment: Alright, @FlyingAtom, please bear with us: can you give us an example of something that `printf ("(%s)\n",item->key);` prints right before `compare()` crashes?

Comment: @Mike Nakis My first is always Null(Root of BST) then it prints things like Apple, Orange, Banana etc. *Headache* LOL

Comment: Are you perhaps compiling with optimizations enabled?

Comment: @Mike nope i do normal GCC Code. Why? Is there a better way for me to debug with/without optimisation or ?

Comment: You should always debug without optimizations.  I am asking because optimizations are one thing that I know of which does, on occasion, cause errors to be reported at a place which is different from the place where they really occurred.  ("Really" as far as we silly humans are concerned.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your clarification about what is being printed, the only thing I can guess is that your compiler is trolling you, and the segfault is not really happening in your invocation of `compare(item->key, key);` but within `strcmp()`.

`printf()` checks for null arguments, so if `item->key` is null, then `printf()` will print "`null`".  On the other hand, `strcmp()` does not check for `null`, and it will crash if you pass `null` to it.  A crash on `compare()` just does not make any sense at all.

Of course it should be noted that compilers are not known to troll people.  There must be a better explanation.

Comment: Ahh so what you are saying is , if i put null in strcmp, i get Segmentation error?

Comment: Yes.  While passing null to `compare()` should be perfectly fine.

Comment: You are indeed an expert! Thank you :)

Comment: Excuse me, what happened? You protected against null and it worked? Still that does not answer the question of why the segfault was reported on the call to `compare()` and not within `strcmp()`. Are you compiling with optimizations enabled?

Comment: I dont think i did any GCC with optimization. I jsut disabled the strcmp and it worked. Now i'm trying to catch null , i guess that would solve the problem :O

Answer (score 1):

You did initialize `item`, but you didn't assign `item->key` properly. `item->key` still points to somewhere uninitialized.

Comment: Sorry , newbie here, If print can access it , why cant my function do the same? :O

Comment: It's undefined behavior. "Print can access it" does not guarantee that "your function can do the same." Indeed it is not guaranteed that "print can access it" either.

Comment: In order to get a thorough answer, you should provide the definition of your `struct item`. @timrau's answer makes likely assumptions about why you're getting a seg fault, but we don't know if those assumptions hold up without knowing what the struct fields are.